# Calculating a Sum with case sensitive

Tags: mongodb

Picture of the table

[image: 1]

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("62f6e11df737d6c2b49b9b9f"),
        "_ID" : 345,
        "name" : "Ron",
        "age" : 25,
        "city" : "Holon",
        "Number_Days_booked" : 2
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("62f6e11df737d6c2b49b9ba0"),
        "_ID" : 459,
        "name" : "Ifat",
        "age" : 25,
        "city" : "Holon",
        "Number_Days_booked" : 4
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("62f6e11df737d6c2b49b9ba1"),
        "_ID" : 789,
        "name" : "Oren",
        "age" : 26,
        "city" : "ramla",
        "Number_Days_booked" : 3
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("62f6e11df737d6c2b49b9ba2"),
        "_ID" : 324,
        "name" : "Gali",
        "age" : 28,
        "city" : "Ramla",
        "Number_Days_booked" : 5
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("62f6e11df737d6c2b49b9ba3"),
        "_ID" : 123,
        "name" : "Adi",
        "age" : 34,
        "city" : "Tel_aviv",
        "Number_Days_booked" : 3
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("62f6e11df737d6c2b49b9ba4"),
        "_ID" : 456,
        "name" : "Dan",
        "age" : 36,
        "city" : "tel_aviv",
        "Number_Days_booked" : 4
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("62f6e11df737d6c2b49b9ba5"),
        "_ID" : 678,
        "name" : "Ronht",
        "age" : 39,
        "city" : "Holon",
        "Number_Days_booked" : 6
}
```

I am trying to calculate the Sum of Number_days_booked only for Tel Aviv, but I have case sensitivity issue.

I have tried so far ->

```
db.Customers.aggregate({ $group: { "_id": { $toLower: "$city" }, "count": { $sum: "$Number_Days_booked" } } })
```

But that produces the sum of all cities and I want to represent only Tel Aviv, how can I do so?

Answer (score 0):

```
        db.Customers.aggregate({ 
    $group: { "_id": { $toLower: "$city" }, "count": { $sum: "$Number_Days_booked" } } },
{$match:{_id:"tel_aviv"}})
```

matching at the end did the trick.

Comment: Would suggest filtering the documents by `city: tel_aviv` first, then perform group by. This will improve the query performance.